# Amazon EC2 : High resources usage although I have no running instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

At the end of last month, I started experimenting with Amazon EC2. I launched one or two t2 micro instances, to experiment for free under the free tier.

However, I have quickly noticed on my billing dashboard that my services usage was increasing fast, and after a few dayswas forecast to exceed the free tier limitations by the end of the month. Since I don't need to maintain an 24/7 online presence at the moment and mostly use my instances to experiment, I have terminated one and stopped another. I have even detached the volume of the stopped instance.

All I have left are:

- One stopped micro instance
- One detached volume
- Two snapshots of that volume
- One AMI that I had used to move my instance from one region to another in the beginning

As far as I understand it, those more or less "idle" resources, at least not highly active ones. And yet, in my billing dashboard, in the row `EC2 - Linux`, the month-to-date usage keeps increasing, at the rate of more than one hour of usage per real-time hour.

Before I detached the volume, the usage would increase by 14 hours in only 3 hours. Now that I have detached it, it slowed down a bit, but still increased by 16 hours in the last 13 hours. All that, again, without actively running anything!

I am aware that the tally of the usage isn't strictly limited to running instances, but to associated resources as well. But still, it seems very high to me. I don't even dare to test my app anymore.

I would like to know if such an increase is normal, or if there may be something wrong with my account and how I configured my instances. If it is normal, any indications as to what actions I could take to reduce this increase would be very welcome!

Note that I did contact the Amazon support several days ago and didn't get a single reply, this is why I'm turning to here.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Solved. I did have an instance running in another region, probably by mistake because I had never interacted directly with that region. See comments for a script to systematically check all regions and avoid this kind of stupid mistake.

Comment: Did you check all regions to ensure you didn't leave any instances running?

Comment: Here's a Ruby script to enumerate instances across all regions (https://www.p8952.info/aws/2014/12/11/aws-listing-all-regions.html) and here's a more generic tool to enumerate resources across regions (https://github.com/scopely-devops/skew).

Comment: I actually had an instance running in another region, which explains the problem... the thing is, I had no recollection of ever running an instance in that region, I probably did it by mistake. A tool to enumerate it systematically will be useful, thanks!